# Finding the number of rows for all files within a folder

Tags: python, loops, find, rows

Hello I am trying to find the number of rows for all files within a folder. I am trying to do this for a folder that contains only ".txt" files and for a folder that contains ."csv" files.

I know that the way to get the number of rows for a SINGLE ".txt" file is something like this:

```
file = open("sample.txt","r") 
Counter = 0
  
Content = file.read() 
CoList = Content.split("\n") 
  
for i in CoList: 
    if i: 
        Counter += 1
          
print("This is the number of lines in the file") 
print(Counter)
```

Whereas for a SINGLE ".csv" file is something like this:

```
file = open("sample.csv")
reader = csv.reader(file)
lines= len(list(reader))
print(lines)
```

But how can I do this for ALL files within a folder? That is, how can I loop each of these procedures across all files within a folder and, ideally, export the output into an excel sheet with columns akin to these:

```
Filename  Number of Rows
1.txt     900
2.txt     653
```

and so on and so on.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: see [os](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.listdir) module. `for file_name in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f)): open(file_name, 'r')...`

Comment: This would work but I find it easier to use the `glob` module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `glob` to detect the files and then just iterate over them.

Other methods : [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

```py
import glob

# 1. list all text files in the directory
rel_filepaths = glob.glob("*.txt")

# 2. (optional) create a function to read the number of rows in a file
def count_rows(filepath):
  res = 0
  f = open(filepath, 'r')
  res = len(f.readlines())
  f.close()

  return res

# 3. iterate over your files and use the count_row function
counts = [count_rows(filepath) for filepath in rel_filepaths]

print(counts)
```

Then, if you want to export this result in a `.csv` or `.xslx` file, I recommend using `pandas`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# 1. create a new table and add your two columns filled with the previous values
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Filename"] = rel_filepaths
df["Number of rows"] = counts

# 2. export this dataframe to `.csv`
df.to_csv("results.csv")
```

You can also use `pandas.ExcelWriter()` if you want to use the `.xlsx` format. Link to documentation & examples : [Pandas - ExcelWriter doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)